# Rails parameter not being passed on post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, selector

In the controller for this (index) view the variable @eventtypes is assigned 4 values (sport, concert, comedy & theatre)

Then the form below retrieves the 4 options and shows them in a drop down menu (HTML select box)

Problem: When I submit this form the index view shows the eventname & number but the eventtype is blank. I am a total noob but I suspect that I need to have an "f." something in the line that begins "<%= select".

Please help me to understand the solution. I am using the latest Rails 4 and Ruby 2.0.0

```
<%= form_for(@tix) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :eventname %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :eventname %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :eventtype %><br>
    <%= select(:eventtype, :eventtype, @eventtypes.collect {|e| [ e.category, e.id ] })  %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, you need a `f.` in front of the `select`.

Comment: yeah you need to say f.select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax was

```
<%= f.select(:eventtype, @eventtypes.collect {|p| [p.category] }, { include_blank: true }) %>
```

Note: The link http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select has incorrect syntax as it is missing a '(' before the first ':eventtype'

Answer (score 1):

You're probably picking up [`Kernel#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-select) when you say:

```
<%= select(:eventtype, :eventtype, @eventtypes.collect {|e| [ e.category, e.id ] })  %>
```

You want the [`select` form helper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select):

```
<%= f.select(...
```

Consult the documentation for the correct arguments.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I did try that buy adding the 'f.' creates an error... "undefined method `merge' for [["Concert", 1], ["Sport", 2], ["Theatre", 3], ["Comedy", 4]]:Array"

Comment: That's because you're passing the options array where it expects some options: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select